# Prevent multiple instances of windows

Tags: wpf

How could I prevent opening multiple windows from a wpf application?

I need to open a window from the menu and if I click to open it again, I want the already opened window to become active.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `Application.Current.Windows` collection for that. Just check whether this collection contains the window you are about to open and if it does, activate it, otherwise create new window and show it:

```
var existingWindow = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => /* return "true" if 'w' is the window your are about to open */);

if (existingWindow != null) {
    existingWindow.Activate();
}
else {
    // Create and show new window
}
```

Comment: What should be given after the lamda expression?

Comment: I first use foreach (var w in Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>()) { MessageBox.Show(w.GetType().ToString()); YourWindow pp = new YourWindow(); } to get the YourWindow's type name from the MsgBox, then I put w => { return w.GetType().ToString() == "YourWindow's type name"; } in the lambda, in else I put y = new YourWindow(); y.Show(); other the same as in the answer, then success .    here have the similar method  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202101/how-do-i-know-if-a-wpf-window-is-opened

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
private Window _otherWindow;

private void OpenWindow()
{
   if (_otherWindow == null)
   {
      //Pass in a reference to this window so OtherWindow can call WindowClosed when it is closed..
      _otherWindow = new OtherWindow(this);

      _otherWindow.Show();

   }
   else
      _otherWindow.Activate();  //Or whatever the method is to bring a window to the front

}

public void WindowClosed()
{
    _otherWindow = null;
}
```

Comment: How can be the open and close in the same? We write the open in the main form and the close in the child form right?